# Group by Distinct using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, distinct

I want to distinctly merge two or more collections on an id and create a collection of the other property for each id.

I have an object `foo`

```
public class foo
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string color { get; set; }
}
```

Which I have multiple `List<foo>` which have common **id's** but with different colors

```
//list 1
id = 1, color = "red"
id = 2, color = "blue"
id = 3, color = "green"
id = 1, color = "blue"
id = 2, color = "orange"
//list 2                
id = 1, color = "black"
id = 2, color = "amber"
id = 3, color = "red"
id = 4, color = "red"
id = 2, color = "silver"
```

I want to use linq to project a new collection that will be distinct on the id but create and list of the color property.

```
id = 1, color = { "red", "blue", "black" }
id = 2, color = { "blue", "orange", "amber", "silver" }
id = 3, color = { "green", "red" }
id = 4, color = { "red" }
```

**Q:** How can this be written in **linq**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var colours = list.GroupBy(x => x.id)
                  .Select(x => new {id = x.Key, color = x.Select(y => y.color).ToList()})
                  .ToList();
```

That will give you a list called colours in the structure you want.

If you want the colour field to be a comma separated string then change it to:

```
var colours = list.GroupBy(x => x.id)
                  .Select(x => new {id = x.Key, color = x.Select(y => y.color).ToArray().Join(",")})
                  .ToList();
```

Comment: Yep ive got the two lists together, trying this solution now @Kevin Holditch

Comment: Missing the closing curly braces also @Kevin Holditch

Comment: My bad, all fixed now :)

Comment: The Select "new" will create an Anonymous Type list ,right? Is there a way to do that without creating an anonymous type?

Answer (score 3):

I think you want a `Dictionary<int, List<string>>` instead:

```
Dictionary<int, List<string>> idColors = foos
    .GroupBy(f => f.id)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(f => f.color).ToList());
```

Now you can access every id's color(s) in this way:

```
List<string> colors = idColors[1];
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", colors));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = List.GroupBy(g => new { g.id, g.color })
                         .Select(g => g.First())
                         .ToList();
```

Comment: You may need to add a `Concat` call to demonstrate meshing both `List<Foo>` lists together.

Comment: There are two lists, and this only takes the first color of each group... the result must include all colors

Answer (score 1):

you can use below mentioned code

```
var mergedList = list1.Concat(list2)
                  .GroupBy(person => person.id)
                  .Select(group => group.Aggregate(
                                     (merged, next) => merged.Merge(next)))
                  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
list1.Concat(list2)
    .GroupBy(x => x.id)
    .Select(x => new foo 
                   {  
                      id = x.Key, 
                      color = string.Join(",", x.Select(g => g.color)) 
                   }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 var combinedList = list1;
 combinedList.AddRange(list2);
 var uniqueIds = combinedList.Select(p => p.id).Distinct()

 var result = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
 uniqueIds.ForEach(i => result.Add(i, new List<string>());
 combinedList.ForEach(i => result[i.id].Add(i.color);
```

I haven't tested this, but I think it should be okay... 
Might be a better way of doing it, but this should get you working for the moment!